# selectnav list item with a span inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [selectnav](https://github.com/lukaszfiszer/selectnav.js)

and it works great, but I have a menu with a description span inside the list item. So my menu items look like  this

`<li><a href="somelink.html">Chapter Here <span>description here</span></a></li>`

selectnav returns the list item as `Chapter Heredescriptionhere` but I want to remove that description span. How do I strip out that description span so selectnav returns just `Chapter Here` .

Hope that makes sense.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stuff = $('li a').clone().children().remove().end().text(); 
alert(stuff);
```

Fully tested with your html.

Comment: hi carter, thanks for answering, unfortunately that didn't work for me. The second thing is I will have loads of menu items with the spans, from wordpress, so need to strip out the spans automatically without asking jquery to find individual links. :). I must also ONLY strip out the spans within selectnav and not before, as they need to be visible on the normal menu view.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Carter, yeah this works, but it's selectnav that's giving me the problem, is there a way to pass that 'stuff' variable to selectnav when it's building the list items into select options?

Comment: I think some confusion around what you are trying to do. You now are saying you actually dont want text returned without span but instead just want spans removed. If that is the case then just use normal selectors to span and then .remove()

Comment: Hi Carter, this won't work because selectnav removes the span tags when building the list item. So the returned select items don't have any span tags, just the text that was in them. I'd like to remove the text surrounded by span tags, when I pass the list to selectnav. Somehow I have to remove the text within span tags ONLY when passing the list to selectnav. I can't use normal selectors as I need the description displayed in full size mode, and when selectnav kicks in, descriptions removed. The idea is a main menu with description, but when resized, changes to selectnav menu without desc

Comment: copy text in span tags like I did above and attach it to a dom element which doesn't get changed via .data() or data attribute such as data-conditional-text and then you can just display the full text when large screen by adding span tags back in after select nav has done its thing.  Or store both versions of text in data attributes and depending on situation change the text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        $(this).find('span').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: He doesn't want to remove spans, he wants the text outside of spans and inside of a tags.  My code will accomplish that.